# Ext.data.Model Validator OR Empty?

Tags: extjs

How can one set a field validator only if the field is not empty?

Eg: I want a validator to check for a url only if there is a value (like empty is allowed). 
In the lower example, website should be allowed to be empty OR be a url.

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'integer' },
        { name: 'website', type: 'string', validators: ['url'] }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own validator with a similar regex. Check https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/src/Url.js.html for the original version.

Appending `^$|` you allow empty string as well.

Have a look here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30o9

Comment: I was trying to avoid as much as possible the usage of custom validators, but it's ok! Thanks!

Comment: You could write an override for the format validator to add a property to allow empty values as well.